# How can i find the decimal values with a list of integers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I am trying to find the best fit formula I can for some crafting numbers in a game, and from what i gather, the game works with decimals and outputs a whole number (not sure about rounding). The problem is, it appears to increment with a fraction around 0.2 and 0.25 (estimate), and I do not know how to find a rough estimate to work with.

**How would I go about finding a rough decimal value, based on a sequence of numbers?** (considering the amount of numbers, i placed them into a spreadsheet)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vnlVfrlJbLR7KUUp4vPTrKt6F86SywEQHhpqqV2YXfM/edit?usp=sharing This should give some context to the numbers i'm working with (work in progress). If it isn't clear, Stat1 and 2 are the numbers i can increase, and the 100/120% columns are the result.

Just FYI, the columns for 100% and 120% are there, because there are multiple skills with varying percentages that modify the base calculation. It also helped me determine the game did the calculations with decimals.

EDIT: I decided to add a few numbers for context, just in case i take down the spreadsheet linked.

```
Stat1   100%    120%        Stat2   100%
21      6       7           0       33
22      6       7           1       33
23      6       7           2       33
24      6       7           3       34
25      6       8           4       34
26      7       8           5       34
27      7       8           6       35
28      7       8           7       35
29      7       9           8       35
30      7       9           9       36
31      8       9           10      36
32      8       9           11      36
33      8       10          12      37
34      8       10          13      37
35      8       10          14      37
...                         ...
115     24      29          50      49
116     25      30          51      50
117     25      30          52      50
118     25      30          53      51
119     25      30          ...
120     26      31          100     66
...                         101     67
164     34      41          102     67
165     35      42          103     68
166     35      42
167     35      42
168     35      42
169     36      43
```

Comment: I am not sure what tags would best fit my question, as well as any similar questions. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it helps anyone, here is the current known formula, which is only slightly off.  `result=(2.09860E-05 * Stat1 * Stat1 + 0.196184 * Stat1 + 2.68452)` This is why i'm looking for a better formula, because this seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

For a rough calculation, you can just take the top and bottom points and see the ratio of the changes. As Stat1 goes from $21$ to $35$, $100\%$ increases from $6$ to $8$.  The multiplier would then be about $\frac {8-6}{35-21}=\frac 17 \approx 0.14$  This may not be very accurate because the range in $100$ is so small and you may be close to or far from a breakpoint. Using the larger range available from your linked spreadsheet where the point $(178,37)$ is available, you would get $\frac {37-6}{178-21}=\frac {31}{156}$ which is *very* close to $\frac 15=0.2$.  I would bet heavily on that.

For a more formal route to estimation you can do a linear regression in a spreadsheet.  I copied some of the data to Excel, did an XY plot, added a linear trendline with the equation shown.  You can read about linear regression in any numerical analysis text to see how this is done.  Here the slope comes out $0.1989$, which is very close to $0.2$
[image]

Comment: This isn't bad, and I have tried it.  However, the number appears to be a little lower, so it doesn't work well if I try to calculate the result on the higher numbers. On top of that, around 116-119 in stat1, it breaks the pattern by giving the same number 4 times instead of 5.  It just took that long before the decimal affected it. It does it again at 165-168, just for reference.